# Exportable class with nested object as property

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an exportable class that has an object as a property in angular 2. The reason for this is so that I can bind my form to it using NgModel.

For example, if I have this object:

```
user: {
  name: string,
  address: {
    street: string,
    city: string,
    state: string
  }
}
```

Currently I have something similar to this:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  address: any;
}
```

Is there a way to make the address property the same as the 'user' object without using the 'any' tag?

Seems like a simple fix, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Thank you

Comment: Shoot. I should have specified I have that user object coming in from Mongo. I am trying to assign it to class User. Would I have to make a separate Address class and use that as the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  // can be single object
  address: {
    city: string,
    street: string,
    state: string
  };
  // can even be array
  addresses: {
    city: string,
    street: string,
    state: string
  }[];
}
```